# Python: read until the first properly-formatted line, catch if there is none

Tags: python

I'm trying to read the first line from a file, that corresponds to some format I specified.

I have a method `self.parse_log_line(line)` that returns an object when the file was properly parsed, otherwise it returns `None`.

So I tried to just read and parse each line, until I get something non-None:

```
with open(filename, 'r') as csv_file:
    line = csv_file.readline()
    info = self.parse_log_line(line) #parse it, None if the line isn't formatted properly
    while info is None:
        line = csv_file.readline()
        info = self.parse_log_line(line)
    # if info is still none, do something to handle that
```

However, for some reason this loops infinitly. Some files can be empty, or contain no properly formatted lines.

How can I fix this? Read until I get a properly formatted line, and if there is none do something else?

Comment: Why don't you just iterate through your file until you find what you are looking for. Once you have exhausted the file, and it is none, proceed with that condition? Using a while loop in this fashion is pretty dangerous for the very reason that it will risk going on in an infinite loop, as you are currently experiencing.

Comment: Hmm, yes, why don't I? I'm trying it now :D

Comment: Ok, idjaw, that works. I now use `for line in csv_file:` and do the parsing in there. Then simply `break` once I find the first proper line. If you add that as an answer I can accept it ;)

Comment: Glad to hear you got it working. I posted the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A better and safer approach here would be to iterate through your file until you find what you are looking for. For example, something like :

```
with open('your_file') as f:
    for line in f:
        # do your logic here

# check for your `None` match here
```

Once you have exhausted the file, and you find a `None`, proceed with your `None` match condition.

Using a while loop in this fashion is pretty dangerous for the very reason that it will risk going on in an infinite loop, as you are currently experiencing.

Comment: I was thinking same exact thing and then scrolled down and saw this :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to check also if there is a line to read (what if there is no more to read and your still reading - infinite loop).

```
with open(filename, 'r') as csv_file:
    line = csv_file.readline()
    info = self.parse_log_line(line) #parse it, None if the line isn't formatted properly
while info is None:
    line = csv_file.readline()
    if line is None:
        #end of file, do what you got to do
    else:
        info = self.parse_log_line(line)
        # if info is still none, do something to handle that
```

Comment: Take a look at the logic in your while loop. It isn't correct. Your if statement is pointless because its testing the same condition as the while loop. So the if statement will run once and then terminate if you don't find what you are looking for in the first line.

Comment: No @Jonathan, the while loop is testing if `info` is None. `info` can be None if parsing of `line` fails even when `line` is different from `None` (maybe the line is not in the appropriate format). 
Again, the while loop checks info and the if checks the line.